# conditional if for many values, better way

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a better way to deal with checking multiple values. It starts to get really busy when I have more than 3 choices.

```
if (myval=='something' || myval=='other' || myval=='third') {

}
```

PHP has a function called `in_array()` that's used like this:

```
in_array($myval, array('something', 'other', 'third'))
```

Is there something like it in js or jquery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Jquery.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Answer (score 3):

Besides `$.inArray`, you could use Object notation:

```
if (myval in {'something':1, 'other':1, 'third':1}) {
   ...
```

or

```
if (({'something':1, 'other':1, 'third':1}).hasOwnProperty(myval)) {
   ....
```

(Note that the 1st code won't work if the client side has modified `Object.prototype`.)

Comment: Well, it will work, it just might give you a false positive. Note also that the quote marks are superfluous. And finally note that—while this works for the OP's specific case very well—it only works when comparing string values.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid iterating over the array by using some kind of a hash map:

```
var values = {
    'something': true,
    'other': true,
    'third': true
};

if(values[myVal]) {

}
```

Does also work without jQuery ;)

Comment: if (values.hasOwnProperty(myval)) would safeguard against finding a property up the prototype chain.

Comment: Though this is an excellent suggestion for the OP's particular case, it might bear pointing out that it only works when looking for string values.

Answer (score 0):

a clean solution taken from the [10+ JAVASCRIPT SHORTHAND CODING TECHNIQUES](http://www.jquery4u.com/javascript/shorthand-javascript-techniques/#d_clip_container_38):

**longhand**

```
if (myval === 'something' || myval === 'other' || myval === 'third') {
    alert('hey-O');
}
```

**shorthand**

```
if(['something', 'other', 'third'].indexOf(myvar) !== -1) alert('hey-O');
```